# How to initialize terraform variables in Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, azure-pipelines

I have the following variables defined in my terraform variables file:

```
variable "environment" {
  type = string
}
variable "resource_group" {
  type = object({
    name        = string
    location    = string
  })
}
```

I initialize them in terraform.tfvars files per the following code snippet:

```
environment = "Dev"
resource_group = {
  name = "mytestresourcegroup"
  location = "Canada Central"
}
```

I have a build pipeline in Azure DevOps that runs my terraform implementation and creates the azure resources successfully. This is great, but it's not a scalable solution to create the resources in another environment e.g. production.

How can I initialize `environment` and `resource_group` variables' values int he Azure DevOps pipeline to something else so that for e.g. `environment` becomes "prod" or "uat", etc.? More importantly the `resource_group` is a more complex object and the question is how to initialize the `name` and the `location`.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is to have a separate `tf.vars` file for each environment whose name will match you ADO pipeline environments. Once this is configured the ADO environment `dev`, `uat`, `prd` will be passed through your ADO pipeline to your terraform step via parameter substitution and map to the correct environment variable file.

I'd recommend a separate `tf.vars` file per environment as opposed to one that is overwritten as this will create a terraform dependency on your ADO pipelines. By creating a separate `.tfvars` for each environment then your terraform is more agnostic from your build/deployment process.

Here is a [blog post](https://blog.johnfolberth.com/terraform-ci-cd-azure-devops-and-yaml-templates/) detailing in depth how to achieve this and provides sample code.